# In Chrome DevTools, is there a way to start recording of Network, Timeline and Profiles at the same time?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Each of the Chrome DevTools(Network, Timeline, Profiles) has a Start/Stop button with shortcut Ctrl+E.  From what I've been able to see, the Timeline has the best overall information, but Network and Profiles offer more specific information.  Does anyone know if there is a way to start all three at the same time?  Or must I rerun a test three times to capture information from each tool separately?

I've looked through the Chrome DevTools documents and have done other searching but haven't seen this specific question asked or answered.
An alternative would be if the Timeline tool could give more detailed information on the network calls being made similarly to the Network tool.

Answer (score 0):

You currently need to retest in each. Displaying more detailed network information in the timeline panel is being worked on. It is currently an experiment.

1. Go to `chrome://flags#enable-devtools-experiments` and enable DevTools Experiments.
2. Restart Chrome
3. Open DevTools
4. Go to Settings > Experiments tab on the left side.
5. Press shift 6 times (so pro right?)
6. Enable `Network requests on Timeline`
7. Restart DevTools

This will then show network requests on the timeline. However, this is experimental. Final UX may change or the feature could be removed at any point, be warned.